# html textarea not showing value inside textarea in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to display plain text inside textarea that i'm loading from controller through model in view. but it's not showing  inside text area

```html
 @foreach (DsplayModel display in ViewBag.Controls)
 {
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerAction", "ControllerToPost",     FormMethod.Post}
    {
    
    //try 1
    <textarea id="txtArea" class="form-control mt-15" rows="3" maxlength="500" asp-for="UserComment">
    @display.UserComment
    </textarea>
    }
    //try 2
     @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.UserComment, new { id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Name", Value = @display.UserComment })
    
 }
```

My 1st try render as a

```
<textarea id="txtArea" class="form-control mt-15" rows="3" maxlength="500" asp-for="UserComment"></textarea>
```

My 2nd try render as a

```
<textarea id="NameBox" name="UserComment" placeholder="Name" Value="Hello">
```

//
In 2nd try my value is loading in textarea i.e. Value="Hello" but not inside textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display plain text inside textarea that i'm loading from
> controller through model in view. but it's not showing inside text
> area

You can try following way, if you would like to load `textarea` from your `ViewBag`

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var dsplayModelList = new List<DsplayModel>()
            {
                new DsplayModel() { UserComment="This is some comment from viewbag"},
                new DsplayModel() { UserComment="This is another comment from viewbag"},

            };
            ViewBag.Controls = dsplayModelList;
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@model DotNetWebApp.Models.DsplayModel

@foreach (DsplayModel display in ViewBag.Controls)
{

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerAction", "ControllerToPost", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <textarea name="NameBox" placeholder = "Name" class="form-control">@display.UserComment</textarea>
       
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]

**From Model:**

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var dsplayModel = new DsplayModel();
        dsplayModel.UserComment = "This is some comment from Model";
        
        return View(dsplayModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@model DotNetWebApp.Models.DsplayModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerAction", "ControllerToPost", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.UserComment)

}
```

**Note:** If you need list, just use foreach loop.

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="4">@Model.UserComment</textarea>
```

Comment: maybe you have wrong in syntax   
   '@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerAction", "ControllerToPost",     FormMethod.Post}'
=>
 '@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerAction", "ControllerToPost", FormMethod.Post))'

Comment: That just post method  for submitting data. I want to load data from controller that is text inside textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try 1
@foreach (DsplayModel display in @ViewBag.Controls)                                                         {
    <textarea id="txtArea" class="form-control mt-15" rows="3" 
    maxlength="500" 
   asp-for="UserComment">
    @display.UserComment
    </textarea>
}

//Try 2
@foreach (DsplayModel display in @ViewBag.Controls)                                                         {
   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.UserComment, new { id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Name", Value = @display.UserComment })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).